# Displaying of MySQL database into HTML coded table via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I tried this code to display MySQL data into coded HTML table via PHP:

```
<?php
    // Get all the data from the "login" table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login") or die(mysql_error());

    echo '<table class="table">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>FirstName</th> 
                  <th>LastName</th> 
                  <th>user</th> 
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>';

    // keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
        **if( $i % 2 == 0 )** {  //line 20
            $class = " class='odd'";
        }
        else {
            $class = "";
        }
        // Print out the contents of each row into a table
        echo "<tr" . $class . "><td>"; 
        echo $row['FirstName'];
        echo "</td><td>"; 
        echo $row['LastName'];
        echo "</td><td>"; 
        echo $row['user'];
        echo "</td><td>";  
    }
    echo "</tbody></table>";
?>
```

But it shows me this error:

> Undefined variable: i in line 20

The line 20 error text is marked as bold in above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 $i=0;
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    if( $i % 2 == 0 ) {
        $class = " class='odd'";
    } else {
        $class = "";

    }
    // Print out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr" . $class . "><td>"; 
    echo $row['FirstName'];
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $row['LastName'];
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $row['user'];
    echo "</td><td>";  
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add `$i=0;` before the `while` loop starts,
and also increment it `$i++` before `while` loop ends.

```
$i = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

//your code

  $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vora, thanks very very much

Comment: Accept an answer that solved your problem by ticking the mark under the score

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
$i = 0;
```

before the `while` where you are getting the error and use $i++ on you evaluation

Answer (score 0):

You were never incrementing your `$i`

```
$i = 0; 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
  if($i % 2 == 0)
  ....

  $i++;  //You need to increment your $i
}
```